# How to pass back actionlink values - mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have following code in `HomeController`; it gets latest date and shows songs according to that date.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{           
   var topsong = db.TopSongs;
   var topDate = db.TopDates;
   var latestDate = topDate.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();
   int dateId = topDate.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateId).FirstOrDefault().DateId;
   var topTitles = topsong.Where(s => s.DateId == latestDate.DateId).ToList();

   ViewBag.Message = "Top Songs";                                    
   ViewBag.latestDate = latestDate.Date.ToShortDateString();            

   return View(topTitles);
}
```

This goes into database and picks latest date -- let's say 08/25/2012 -- and shows all songs corresponding to this date. This part is working fine; now I want to add a feature where the user can select previous dates or next dates from the database, and display songs according to that.

What I am trying to do is add previous and next date buttons in the View. Like this:

```
<h2>Songs Updated On: @ViewBag.latestDate</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Previous Week's Songs", "Index", new { });
@Html.ActionLink("Next Week's Songs", "Index", new { });
```

As I am new to MVC3, can someone please tell me how can I get previous and next dates to show up?  If I calculate them in the View, how can I pass them back to controller to show songs for those dates?

Here is the example dates table:
DateId        Date
1             08/25/2012
2             08/20/2012
3             09/21/2012

**Updated Code:**

*Here is code for HomeController:*

```
 public ActionResult Index(DateTime? date = null)
        {            
            var topsong = db.TopSongs;
            var topDate = db.TopDates;

            var latestDate = (date.HasValue) ? date.Value : topDate.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();           


            //var latestDate = topDate.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();

            int dateId = topDate.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateId).FirstOrDefault().DateId;           
            var topTitles = topsong.Where(s => s.DateId == latestDate.DateId).ToList();

            /////
            ViewBag.NextDate = topDate.Where(d => d.Date > latestDate).OrderBy(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();
            ViewBag.PreviousDate = topDate.Where(d => d.Date < latestDate).OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();
            ////////

            ViewBag.Dates = topDate.Select(d => d.Date).Distinct();
            ViewBag.latestDate = latestDate.Date.ToShortDateString();            

            return View(topTitles);
        }
```

*Code for Index.cshtml*

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Models.TopSong>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Top Songs";
    var songs = ViewBag.songs;
}            
<h1>@ViewBag.Message</h1>

<h2>Song's Updated On: @ViewBag.latestDate</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Previous Week's Songs", "Index", new { date=@ViewBag.PreviousDate });
@Html.ActionLink("Next Week's Songs", "Index", new { date=@ViewBag.NextDate });
```

Basically i just want to be able to go to previous or next date using action links. I tried above code but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is as follows:

First, create an action method

```
Public ActionResult Songs(string val)
{
   if (val == "Previous")
   {
    // code to get and return previous week songs
   }

   if (val == "Next")
   {
    // code to get and return next week songs
   }

    // By default return either previous/next/current week's songs...
}
```

Second, modify your action links to match as below

```
@Html.ActionLink("Previous Week's songs", "Songs", new { val = "Previous"})

@Html.ActionLink("Next Week's Songs", "Songs", new { val = "Next"})
```

**Another Approach:**

Another approach is to create an action method for each, that means you can have an action method to just return Previous Week's Songs and another action method to return Next Week's songs. This means you will not need to pass any arguments and your actionlink code will look as simple as below

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Previous Week's songs", "PreviousWeekSongs")

   @Html.ActionLink("Next Week's Songs", "NextWeekSongs")
```

**UPDATE:**

Hey it seems like you do not have any code specific to binding your model data back to the View...so try updating your View code as below

```
    @model IEnumerable<App.Models.TopSong>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Top Songs";
    var songs = ViewBag.songs;
}            
<h1>@ViewBag.Message</h1>
// Code to Display Songs
@foreach(var song in model)
{
  <div> 
   <span>@song.Property1</span>
   <span>@song.Property2</span>
   <span>@song.Property3</span>          
  </div>

}

<h2>Song's Updated On: @ViewBag.latestDate</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Previous Week's Songs", "Index", new { date=@ViewBag.PreviousDate });
@Html.ActionLink("Next Week's Songs", "Index", new { date=@ViewBag.NextDate });
```

I hope this may help you...

Comment: Hi, i did not post the code for posting songs. That is working for me already. My question is specific to how will PreviousDate and NextDate work? As above code for PreviousDate and NextDate is not working. Its giving me error on latestDate and i am not sure what this new { date=@ViewBag.PreviousDate } statement is passing back to Controller?

Comment: ok...if your question was specific to how previous and next date work? then you may follow my first advice which is prior to the "UPDATE" section ...that must be pretty straight forward...

Comment: NiK- Thanks NiK i will try that and see if i can make it work as i tried the above code by dbaseman but was getting error on implementing latestDate but i will try your version also and see if i could solve this problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, the answer is to create a *View Model*.  The idea here is to provide all the data needed by your view.  For example:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string CurrentDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime NextDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime PreviousDate { get; set; }
    public List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}
```

So, you'll populate this as needed, eg

```
var topDate = db.TopDates;
var model = new ViewModel();
model.Songs = ...
model.CurrentDate = latestDate.Date.ToShortDateString();
model.NextDate = topDate.Where(d => d.Date > latestDate).OrderBy(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault(d => d.Date);
model.PreviousDate = topDate.Where(d => d.Date < latestDate).OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault(d => d.Date);
```

Now you can create the links in the Razor view using values from the model:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Previous Week's Songs", "Index", new { date=Model.PreviousDate });
@Html.ActionLink("Next Week's Songs", "Index", new { date=Model.NextDate });
```

Finally, to handle the links in the postback, add a parameter to the Action method that matches the route value specified above (`date`).

```
public ActionResult Index(int? date = null)
{
    var latestDate = (date.HasValue) ? date.Value : db.TopDates.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault(d => d.Date);
    // same logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code and explanation! Just have one question. model.PreviousDate = latestDate.AddDays(-1); this will give previous date right? But i want dates to be populated from database. I updated my question. Can you please explain how that can be done?

Comment: @NoviceMe right ... I updated my answer.  Not sure exactly how your database is, but you should be able to use some Linq to get the previous/next dates.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I have been trying above code for hour or so now but it is not working. var latestDate = (date.HasValue) ? date.Value : db.TopDates.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault(); //// is giving me error saying cant convert int to type db.topdates. Also nextDate and previousDate seems to not get the dates as desired. And any particular reason why we should pass date as int back from view? Any suggestions?

Comment: @NoviceMe sorry, I didn't mean it as working code, just an example.  If you like, post your updated code so I can see?

Comment: I added updated code. Its still not working. Please if you have time look at it and point out if you see something is wrong. Thanks again for all your help!